# Translating routes with react-18next in react-router-om

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-i18next

I'm working on implementing internalization on my react app. I'm using the starter template from `react-i18next` and the translation/language switch works.

Here's the i18n config

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

i18n.use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        lang: 'en',
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        debug: true,

        backend: {
            loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
        },
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false
        },

        order: [
            'path',
            'querystring',
            'cookie',
            'localStorage',
            'sessionStorage',
            'navigator',
            'htmlTag',
            'subdomain'
        ]
    });

export default i18n;
```

My only issue is that I don't know how to translate the urls. All routes are translated in the json file from locales. I'm using `react-router-dom` for the routing and so far I have made this:

```
<Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
    <Route path={t('routes.home')} element={<HomePage t={t} />} />
    <Route path={t('routes.about')} element={<AboutPage t={t} />} />
    <Route path={t('routes.contact')} element={<ContactPage t={t} />} />
</Routes>
```

The issue is that it doesn't work when I change the language. If I go to it from the navbar it works, or if I type into the address bar the translation of the route. It won't reload the component with proper translation on language change.
Here is my language switcher:

```
<button onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage('fr')}>
    FR
</button>
<button onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage('en')}>
    EN
</button>
```

Comment: Where are the buttons to change language located in relation to the routes? Would triggering a rerender be sufficient to rerender the routes with updated path strings in the new language?

Comment: In the navbar. If I just refresh the page it doesn't work. I think it needs to load the current component on the different language, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Refreshing the page is the same as reloading the app, in other words, the entire app is remounted. Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Could you try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Sure, here it is
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-sun-qp0ji?file=/src/styles.css
After you change the language(top right), you need to click on navbar item to load the component with the new locale.

Comment: The code in the codesandbox appears to be working. I see the route paths change values when switching the language. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: It does, just that when you change the language it doesn't reload the page you're on with the new locale and url, right?

Comment: That would require a navigation to the new page/path, you're effectively changing all the routes that can be rendered. None of the `en` routes match any of the `ro` routes.

Comment: Well yes, the routes and routing are working fine now. I'm not sure how to update the url when the language is changed though.
I updated the sandbox, my guess is that it has to be done in handleLocale on navbar

Comment: FWIW I don't know how common it is for apps to translate their URLs, seems a bit extreme/excessive/unnecessary. I suppose you could grab the current location pathname, search the translation values for the route key, apply the translation, then use the route key to access the new path translation value.